# Improve code for copying/pasting

Tags: vba, excel

I need to reduce the code where am I writing the synatx manytimes for copying and pasting the row values.

```
Private Sub btn_upload_Click()
'Frm_Mainform.Show
'MsgBox ("Process Complete - Please Check File in Output Folder")
Const FOLDER As String = "C:\SBI_Files\"

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

Dim i As Integer
i = 18

Dim fileName As String

fileName = Dir(FOLDER, vbDirectory)

  Do While Len(fileName) > 0

If Right$(fileName, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right$(fileName, 3) = "xls" Then
    i = i + 1

    Dim currentWkbk As Excel.Workbook
     Set currentWkbk = Excel.Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & fileName)
     Cells(i, 1) = fileName
     Cells(i + 1, 2) = "Equity"
     Cells(i + 2, 2) = "Forex NOOP"
     Cells(i + 3, 2) = "Fixed   Income Securities  ( including CP, CD, G Sec)"
     Cells(i + 4, 2) = "Total"
     Cells(i, 2) = "Details"
     Cells(i, 3) = "Limit"
     Cells(i, 4) = "Min Var"
     Cells(i, 5) = "Max Var"
     Cells(i, 6) = "No. of Breaches"
     Cells(i + 1, 3) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("G8:G8").Value
     Cells(i + 1, 4) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("H8:H8").Value
     Cells(i + 1, 5) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("I8:I8").Value
     Cells(i + 1, 6) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("J8:J8").Value
     i = i + 1
     Cells(i + 1, 3) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("G9:G9").Value
     Cells(i + 1, 4) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("H9:H9").Value
     Cells(i + 1, 5) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("I9:I9").Value
     Cells(i + 1, 6) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("J9:J9").Value
     i = i + 1
     Cells(i + 1, 3) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("G10:G10").Value
     Cells(i + 1, 4) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("H10:H10").Value
     Cells(i + 1, 5) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("I10:I10").Value
     Cells(i + 1, 6) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("J10:J10").Value
     i = i + 1
     Cells(i + 1, 3) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("G11:G11").Value
     Cells(i + 1, 4) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("H11:H11").Value
     Cells(i + 1, 5) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("I11:I11").Value
     Cells(i + 1, 6) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("J11:J11").Value
     i = i + 1
     currentWkbk.Close
End If
fileName = Dir
Loop

ProgramExit:
   Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit
End Sub
```

Comment: There's no need to specify `"G8:G8"`. A simple `.Range("G8").Value` will do. Also, I think this should be in a `For` loop rather than in a `Do-While` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace all your `Cells` lines with these 4

*update: added line for coping formats*

```
 'other code
 Set currentWkbk = Excel.Workbooks.Open(FOLDER & fileName)
 Cells(i, 1) = fileName
 Cells(i + 1, 2).Resize(4, 1) = Application.Transpose(Array("Equity", "Forex NOOP", "Fixed   Income Securities  ( including CP, CD, G Sec)", "Total"))
 Cells(i, 2).Resize(1, 5) = Array("Details", "Limit", "Min Var", "Max Var", "No. of Breaches")
 Cells(i + 1, 3).Resize(4, 4) = currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("G8:J11").Value
 currentWkbk.Sheets("VaR").Range("G8:J11").Copy Cells(i + 1, 3)
 currentWkbk.Close
```

Comment: I need to apply same colurs while pasting the values(the colors need to be same from where I am copying the data) and  need to apply border for all the data then how I can I modify the existing code.

Comment: Hi Brettdj,the values are not getting copied.Only the colum names and rownames are getting copied.Please help.

Comment: Hi Brettd jthe code is working,thanks a lot.Just let me know how can I format the same colour while pasting the same value

Comment: For the below cells as well I need to apply a particular colour for row and columns headers.I added .colur(36) cell after the code for each line but got object error                                                             (i + 1, 2).Resize(4, 1) = Application.Transpose(Array("Equity", "Forex NOOP", "Fixed   Income Securities  ( including CP, CD, G Sec)", "Total"))
 Cells(i, 2).Resize(1, 5) = Array("Details", "Limit", "Min Var", "Max Var", "No. of Breaches